# Como se puede organizar la salida de información del comando DIR?

Tags: windows, script, cmd, batch

Estoy necesitando realizar un Windows batch (Windows CMD) que lea el contenido de una carpeta genere un archivo de texto llamado que contenga un listado donde para cada archivo se pueda ver: un secuencial con la posición del archivo en el listado , el nombre del archivo, su tamaño y su fecha de modificación.

Ejemplo:

1. Archivo.txt   120kb    26/10/2021 10:00 a.m.
2. prueba.pdf    1100kb   10/10/2021 08:10 a.m.
3. datos.xls     10kb     09/08/2019 05:14 p.m.
4. fotos.png     23kb     07/11/2020 01:23 a.m.

Así sucesivamente con los archivos de un directorio especifico.

Llevo lo siguiente:

```
@echo off
cls

cd\
cd  C:\

forfiles /C "cmd /c echo @FILE @FSIZE @FDATE >> prueba.txt

@Pause
```

¿Como logro agregar el número de cada línea al principio?

Comment: Bienvenido Juan, tu consulta necesita que aportes qué has intentado hasta el momento para poder ayudarte, ¿has intentado algo?

Answer (score 0):

Sí, es posible, pero yo no podía con forfiles.  Usé un bucle for.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a i=1
@for %%f in (*.*) do (
    @echo %%f %%~zf %%~tf !i!
    @set /a i=!i!+1
)

leafs.jpg 96837 02/10/2014 11:07 AM 1
460742.rtfd 184417 08/10/2021 09:27 AM 2
a.txt 14 10/14/2021 02:17 PM 3
barn4-Rebuild.ppk 1486 09/14/2017 09:27 AM 4
```

Comment: Perfecto, eso era lo que estaba buscando, mil gracias Duston por tu gentil ayuda.